# PHP foreach adjust the order

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array that returns a list of times, but it puts in an order like this `01:00:00, 02:00:00, 03:00:00, 04:00:00, 05:00:00, 10:00:00, 11:00:00, 12:00:00`

I am looking to change the order of this to `10:00:00, 11:00:00, 12:00:00, 01:00:00, 02:00:00, 03:00:00, 04:00:00, 05:00:00`

What would be the best way to go about this?

Here is my PHP code:

```
foreach($thursday as $y => $x){
  echo '<tr>';
  foreach($x as $a => $b){
          echo '<td>' . $b . '</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

the $b is the times.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's no meaningful way to order your times like that, aside from descending first on the first digit and ascending on the 2nd digit.

Comment: How the array is fulfilled?

Comment: @sjagr I like that idea, that should work

Comment: Okay, I've added an answer for you.

Comment: Are your times, hours only? Also, would they always be contiguous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways is just 'temporary' increase of time below '10' into the 'next' day while sorting )) If you want to deal with 09 or 08, just modify the condition.

```
$data = explode(', ', '01:00:00, 02:00:00, 03:00:00, 04:00:00, 05:00:00, ' .
                      '10:00:00, 11:00:00, 12:00:00');

usort($data, function($el1, $el2) {
   if ($el1[0] == '0')
       $el1 = strtotime($el1 . ' +1 day');
   else
       $el1 = strtotime($el1);

   if ($el2[0] == '0')
       $el2 = strtotime($el2 . ' +1 day');
   else
       $el2 = strtotime($el2);

   return $el1 > $el2;  
});

var_dump($data);
```

Result

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "10:00:00"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "11:00:00"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "12:00:00"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "01:00:00"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "02:00:00"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "03:00:00"
  [6]=>
  string(8) "04:00:00"
  [7]=>
  string(8) "05:00:00"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very particular solution, but check for the first character to see if it's equal to 1 and output it if so, if not, put it in a buffer to display later after the `foreach` has completed.

```
$append = '';
foreach ($x as $a => $b) {
    if (substr($b, 0, 1) === '1') {
        echo '<td>'.$b.'</td>';
    } else {
        $append .= '<td>'.$b.'</td>';
    }
}
echo $append;
```

From the best I can see, you're trying to sort ascending time from a particular time. Here's a function for that:

```
function sortAscendingFromTime($array, $time = '00:00:00') {
    function cmp($a, $b) {
        if (strtotime($a) == strtotime($b)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (strtotime($a) < strtotime($b)) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    uasort($array, 'cmp');
    $newArray = array();
    $endArray = array();
    $timestamp = strtotime($time);
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if (strtotime($a) < $timestamp) {
            $endArray[] = $a;
        } else {
            $newArray[] = $a;
        }
    }
    return array_merge($newArray, $endArray);
}
```

Comment: What about 11:00:00 ? :s

Comment: @Zerquix18 What about it? Take a look at OP's original array and how it's ordered, then think about how this `foreach` executes through that array.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion. If you're receiving always the array like: `01:00:00, 02:00:00, 03:00:00, 04:00:00, 05:00:00, 10:00:00, 11:00:00, 12:00:00` (I mean, hourly ordered), just in this case you can simple make another array.

```
<?php
    //array with dates.
    $dates = array("01:00:00", "02:00:00", "03:00:00", "04:00:00", "05:00:00", "10:00:00",  "11:00:00", "12:00:00");
    // get the first 5 hours. 
    $newarray = array_slice($dates, 0, 5 );
    // get the last 3 hours.
    $newarray2 = array_slice($dates, 5, 8);
    // now, merge it, putting the last 3 in the start.
    $dates = array_merge($newarray2, $newarray); // and we're done.
```